# How can I display an element relative to an other in Unity without "moving effects"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, layout, position

I'm starting with unity since a few weeks and i'm stuck with some displaying problems.

You can see what I want to achieve here : [image: ScreenShot]

On several of my pages I have a title with an icon on the left and I want it to be at 40px on the left of the title, no matter the size of it.

So I did a prefab with an empty Text for the title, an empty RawImage for the icon and I put that prefab on the center top of the screen.

I link the following C# script on my prefab with the 'string' parameter for the title and the 'Texture' parameter for the icon to display.

```
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TitlePage : MonoBehaviour {

    public string title;
    public Texture texture;

    private Text titlePageText;
    private RawImage iconPage;

    void Awake()
    {
        titlePageText = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>().First();
        iconPage = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<RawImage>().First();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        titlePageText.text = title;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        iconPage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(-titlePageText.rectTransform.rect.width / 2 - 40, iconPage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition.y);
        iconPage.texture = texture;
    }
}
```

The title is set well in the "Start" function, the problem is with the icon. The code in the "Update" function put the icon at the wanted position if it's in the "Update" function because in the "Start", 'titlePageText.rectTransform.rect.width' give 0. But with that code in the "Update" function, the icon start with a display by default in the center and nearly instantly it moves on the left but we can see that position changing.

Maybe there's a solution to avoid that ?

Maybe I started in a wrong way ?

(I don't put my title's text hardly because I want my application to be multilingual so instead of displaying the 'string' in parameter, I'll display the corresponding translation and it's why I can't set a fixed position because two translations are not the same length.)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what your problem is exactly, but it does sound like you are trying to solve something from a slightly awkward angle. IS there a reason for not using Unity's layout (or even auto layout groups) to achieve your goal?

I just did a quick test: added 'Content Size Fitter component' to the text object with Horizontal set to Preferred, then placed an image as a child of that text object, when I set the anchor X to 0 and pivot X to 1, the image now follows the left hand side of the text, no matter what size.

This has the advantage of doing absolutely zero work unless text (or its position) changes, in which case everything is handled automagically by Unity's UI system

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know the "content size fitter" component and it works very good without any specific code !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the width of the titlePageText is not obtaining a value immediately in Start(), which is why it is initially zero. After a couple of frames when a non-zero value is found, it finally shifts your iconPage over but your object already has a texture at this point. You really shouldn't be doing this in Update() because it means it will constantly be setting the anchoredPosition and texture of your iconPage every frame.

One solution to avoid this would be to use a coroutine with `yield` to wait for your components to initialize and then set the position. Note that this is a bit of a hack since you are introducing some forced loading time.

```
public string title;
public Texture texture;

private Text titlePageText;
private RawImage iconPage;

void Awake()
{
    titlePageText = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>().First();
    iconPage = gameObject.GetComponentsInChildren<RawImage>().First();
}

void Start()
{
    titlePageText.text = title;
    StartCoroutine(initializeComponenets());
}

IEnumerator initializeComponenets()
{
    yield return new waitForSeconds(.05f); //might need longer wait here
    iconPage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(-titlePageText.rectTransform.rect.width / 2 - 40, iconPage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition.y);
    iconPage.texture = texture;
}
```

Comment: `yield return new WaitUntil(titlePageText.rectTransform.rect.width > 0); //wait as long as needed`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as @zambari said in the another response it wasn't the good way to solve my problem. I tried to do a hack like you said ! I tried his solution and it works without specific code.